# Can I use Pivotal's Redis and RabbitMQ for Cloud Foundry on Pivotal Web Services

Tags: redis, rabbitmq, cloud-foundry

Currently, the only RabbitMQ service on PWS looks kinda iffy. I was wondering If I could use Pivotals solutions

- https://network.pivotal.io/products/p-redis
- https://network.pivotal.io/products/pivotal-rabbitmq-service

On Pivotal's own http://run.pivotal.io , or If to run theseI have to have an on premises Cloud Foundry. Can I run these on Pivotal Web Services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the PCF data services such as mysql, rabbitmq, and redis are currently only available for enterprise PCF customers when using PWS. if you contact pivotal-cf-feedback at pivotallabs dot com we can provide more details on the services roadmap for PWS.